# Can't import module in Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, module

I try to import module from existing sources, but got "The project is already registered" error message. I have another 2 sources what I could import in the same way. Only that one causes this problem. Technically there are no differences among these 3 modules.

The main problem could be that once I imported this source as a project instead of module. I suppose that the issue is relating to this failure.
I can't force Idea to forget this cached setting. Following some tip found on internet I tried a lot of things to do so...

**From Idea side:**

Closed the project

Clear recent projects

Gradle refresh / clean etc.

**From file system side:**

I removed .idea folder from the folder of that source

I cleaned up the wrong project name from every human readable file in .IdeaIC2017.1 folder

Uninstall Idea with cache cleanup, then download/install the recent version 2017.2. Even after this step the problem remained!!!!

I don't have so much experience with Idea, but this doesn't help getting love it...
I stucked. Please help!

Comment: I think the cause is ".idea" and "[MODULE_NAME].iml" file. Double check them in both your muldule's directory and parent project's directory

Comment: Your were right! The beast was hiding in the parent project files. I removed the remained folders and .iml files belonging to my module, plus cleaned up workspace.xml and gradle.xml to ensure everything referring to my module is deleted from the parent. That resolved the issue, I could import the module finally.
Thank you very much!